# Gitlab CI - How to start Shared Runner

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm new to Gitlab CI.

I have configured .gitlab-ci.yml file, and using CI Lint it has passed the validation process.

Based on this [documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/quick_start/README), I can see a specific runner should be configured on a virtual machine, a VPS, a bare-metal machine, a docker container or
even a cluster of containers.

But I can see gitlab has its own shared runners and enabled by default.

The question is how to use this shared runner?

When I visit the Pipeline page I can only see the blue **Get Started with Pipeline** button and when clicked I was redirected to [this page](https://gitlab.com/budiantoip/cicd-demo/pipelines).

Here's my .gitlab-ci.yml content :

```
before_script:
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

stage_deploy:
  only:
    - testing
  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$STAGING_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - ssh root@1.2.3.4 "sh update_app.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only run the job for your `testing` branch, have you added the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to that branch too?

Comment: Not yet, let me add it first

Comment: Woah, you just saved my day! I will accept your answer, many thanks!