# Gitlab CI - Start Shared Runner for normal repos

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to Gitlab CI.

I have configured .gitlab-ci.yml file, and using CI Lint it has passed the validation process.

Based on this [documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/quick_start/README), I can see a specific runner should be configured on a virtual machine, a VPS, a bare-metal machine, a docker container or even a cluster of containers.

And I can see gitlab has its own shared runners and *enabled by default*.

When I visit the Pipeline page I can only see the blue **Get Started with Pipeline** button and when clicked I was redirected to [this page](https://gitlab.com/budiantoip/cicd-demo/pipelines).

The "[Gitlab CI - How to start Shared Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635618/)" says that Gitlab CI will only run the job for the `testing` branch, however, none of my git use branch unless for very specific cases. So

The question is how to use this shared runner in my normal (private) repo that has only the single `master` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Shared runners* will run for *any* branch, so for the `master` branch too (unless you configure otherwise).

Additionally,

- you can pick-up a specific runner if you define a [tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags) for your job.
- you can filter if the job will be triggered via [only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified) and/or `except` directives.

For example, following job will trigger for any push, despite the branch:

```yml
buildClient:
  stage: buildComponents
  script:
  - echo "Building the client..."
```

On the other hand, this job will trigger only for push to the `develop` branch and it will be processed by any available runner with the `docker` tag:

```yml
buildServer:
  stage: buildComponents
  script:
  - echo "Building the server with Docker..."
  only:
  - develop
  tags:
  - docker
```

---

According the blue **Get Started with Pipeline** button: You need to add a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to the root of your project and push it to GitLab. This file defines *stages* and *jobs* of your build pipeline. Jobs are then picked-up by runners according the given configuration. E.g. simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` can look like this:

```yml
image: alpine:latest

stages:
  - test
  - build

testApp:
  stage: test
  script: echo "Testing..."

buildApp:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building..."
```

See [Configuration of your jobs with .gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html) in GitLab documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vit. Now that I know Shared runners will run for any branch, the next hurdle I need to overcome is, why when I visit the Pipeline page I can only see the blue Get Started with Pipeline button, even though my shared runners are enabled? There must be a step that I'm missing. thx.

Comment: @xpt I've added an additional explanation at the end of my answer. Once you push your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, this button will disappear and you'll see your pipelines.

Comment: Thanks Vit. Please give me some time to try it and prepare a small demo as I can't make my forked repo public, ref https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40088